# Why doesn’t my query deliver singular results?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, tags

I have following query with `group by` and `having` plus `count`. It should return only those rows having columns specified in the `group by` clause with the count specified by `having count x`.

I think the following query should be correct:

```
@articles = Article.joins(:taggings)
                   .where(taggings: { tag_id: @article_tags_ids, taggable_type: "Article"})
                   .group('articles.id')
                   .having("count(taggings.tag_id) = ?", @article_tags_count)
```

In this case, it should only return those articles, that have those and exactly those tags the user searched for and none more.

Schema is from this tutorial:
https://cobwwweb.com/rails-has-many-through-polymorphic-association

It creates this SQL

```
SELECT
  `articles`.* 
FROM
  `articles` 
INNER JOIN `taggings` 
  ON `taggings`.`taggable_id` = `articles`.`id` 
  AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Article' 
WHERE
  `taggings`.`tag_id` IN (1, 3) 
  AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Article' 
GROUP BY
  articles.id 
HAVING
  (count(taggings.tag_id) = 2) 
LIMIT 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is following SQL Query with not one but **two joins on the join-table.** I don't know what substantial difference that makes, but obviously for the database it does make one, even if it can match articles with tags with a single `join` already.

```
SELECT  
`articles`.*
FROM `articles`
JOIN `taggings` 
ON `articles`.`id` = `taggings`.`taggable_id` 
JOIN `tags` ON `taggings`.`taggable_id` = `tags`.id 
WHERE `tags`.`id` in (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY `articles`.id 
HAVING( COUNT(`tags`.`id`) = 3);
```

Such that when you have two articles, article-one and article-two, where article-one matches tag1, tag2, tag3 and article-two also matches tag1, tag2, tag3 and over that tag4, the query only returns article-one. The conjunction is a "this" `and` "nothing more" and not an `or`

Yours

vonSpotz